# C++ 8 By 8 Board

Tags: c++, function

im trying to implement the n-queen problem board game and im having problems with the board 
so what am i doing wrong here in this displayboard function? its suppose to implement an 8 by 8 empty board sorry im just a beginner

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

const int rows = 8;
const int columns =8;

int board[rows][columns] = {0,0};

void displayboard();

int main(){

displayboard();

system("pause");

}
void displayboard ()
{

cout << "  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" << endl;
cout << "  ---------------";

for (int bRow = 0; bRow<rows; bRow++)
 {
 for (int bCol = 0; bCol<columns; bCol++)

  if (board[bRow][bCol] == 0)
         cout << " ";
  else 
      cout << " ";
  } 
 cout << endl;

  return;
 }
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly your problem is.  Does the code not compile? Is the program crashing? Is the output wrong?

Comment: `int board[rows][columns] = {0,0};` is unnecessary because you declare it in global scope and a little odd if you did it in local scope: `{0}` would be just as good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (board[bRow][bCol] == 0)
      cout << " ";
else 
      cout << " ";
```

?? Both do the same thing ! Printing a blank space. Moreover, you haven't populated your array `board[8][8]` anything other than `0`s.

Comment: The expected output most definitely was **NOT** a sinlge line of roughly 64 spaces.

Comment: @sehe, OP was assuming of getting unexpected output, which is wrong. Removed that line from my answer.

Comment: You can't really know what he expected, so you can't say he was wrong :) My crystal ball seemed to have more power in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the newlines and possible the white spaces per row. here is a fixed version: (I used a '.' to denote an (empty) field - as it is friendlier to human debugging)

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  ---------------
  . . . . . . . . 
  . . . . . . . . 
  . . . . . . . . 
  . . . . . . . . 
  . . . . . . . . 
  . . . . . . . . 
  . . . . . . . . 
  . . . . . . . .
```

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

const int rows = 8;
const int columns =8;

int board[rows][columns] = {0,0};

void displayboard();

int main()
{
    displayboard();
}

void displayboard ()
{
    cout << "  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" << endl;
    cout << "  ---------------";

    for (int bRow = 0; bRow<rows; bRow++)
    {
        cout << "\n  ";
        for (int bCol = 0; bCol<columns; bCol++)
        {
            if (board[bRow][bCol] == 0)
            {
                cout << ".";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << ".";
            }
            cout << " "; // delimiter
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    return;
}
```

Comment: was it intentional that both branches in the inner loop print a dot?

Comment: Yup. It was also intentional that both branches originally printed a space. This code is clearly just the beginning. I imagine that the OP wants to invent... maybe... even chess pieces on there. I answered the question only, not the whole N-Queens problem :)